# Formatting command output that is a long single line

Tags: command-line, output

I am working on vxlan tunneling between Linux - commercial routers. I need to debug some interface settings.

The command `sudo ip -d link show DEV` gives me a great output but the output format is like a long single line as below.

```
katabey@leaf-1:mgmt:~$ sudo ip -d link show vxlan_10
11: vxlan_10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9216 qdisc noqueue master bridge state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:6d:3d:aa:b5:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535 
    vxlan id 10010 local 10.1.1.1 srcport 0 0 dstport 4789 nolearning ttl 64 ageing 300 udpcsum noudp6zerocsumtx noudp6zerocsumrx 
    bridge_slave state forwarding priority 8 cost 100 hairpin off guard off root_block off fastleave off learning off flood on port_id 0x8002 port_no 0x2 designated_port 32770 designated_cost 0 designated_bridge 8000.50:0:0:3:0:3 designated_root 8000.50:0:0:3:0:3 hold_timer    0.00 message_age_timer    0.00 forward_delay_timer    0.00 topology_change_ack 0 config_pending 0 proxy_arp off proxy_arp_wifi off mcast_router 1 mcast_fast_leave off mcast_flood on neigh_suppress on group_fwd_mask 0x0 group_fwd_mask_str 0x0 group_fwd_maskhi 0x0 group_fwd_maskhi_str 0x0 vlan_tunnel off isolated off addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

It would be great to have the output like

```
vxlan id 10010
local 10.1.1.1
srcport 0
dstport 4789
```

I remember a couple of years back Linux system engineers I used to work with doing `command | python ...` but I was not able to find/recall the command. (I have Python installed).

Any other solutions (especially single liners) are welcome.

Comment: is that correct, you want `srcport 0` and not `srcport 0 0`?, also these information always appears at 3rd line of the command's output? and format always same (specially for the 3rd line in output) ?

Comment: source port 0 0 would be fine, something general that will tidy the output would do the trick. yeah mostly the same one key one value

Comment: Not clear how the two rows before vxlan were discarded, or where the fold should occur: most elements have one word and a value, but there are anomalies like `srcport 0 0` and `nolearning ttl 64`. Values are variously numeric,  hex constants, words `on off yes no UNKNOWN DEFAULT` etc. so detailed rules are needed.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to list *all* the output realigned: just the four example values you show is rather simpler (and much less interesting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
your-command |grep -Eo '(vxlan id|srcport|dstport) [0-9]+|local [0-9.]+'
```

Comment: yes this one returned the values i listed and i got the idea thanks alot.

Comment: If you generalize the values as `[^[:blank:]]+` then "local" does not have to be a special case.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the `fmt` command that's part of coreutils.

In particular, you'll want to use

> #### `-s`, `--split-only`
>
> split long lines, but do not refill

Answer (score 0):

If your implementation of `ip` supports the `--json` output format switch, then I'd suggest something like

```
sudo ip -d link show vxlan_10 | jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"'
```

Ex. (I don't have a vlan interface, so this shows a regular wireless interface):

```
$ ip --json link show wls1 | jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"'
ifindex 3
ifname wls1
flags ["BROADCAST","MULTICAST","UP","LOWER_UP"]
mtu 1500
qdisc mq
operstate UP
linkmode DORMANT
group default
txqlen 1000
link_type ether
address 00:21:6a:96:40:12
broadcast ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: you are right i also did "ip --json link show wls1 | python -m json.tool" this also works if i want them all sorted clean. Thankyou.